# View content of PHPSESSID variable/cookie based on its value

Tags: php, session, cookies

When visiting a website (not owned by me) which for example has set a PHPSESSID variable/cookie with value 7er3hjKal8u235c87u6ih0vz8Y, 
is it possible to view its content? I tried print_r($_SESSION); in the console but it says 'ReferenceError: print_r is not defined' . If it is not possible to directly view the content, is there a way to view the traffic or contents which are stored/piped to that PHPSESSID? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `print_r()` in the console, because the console is for executing JavaScript, so you can't execute PHP functions in the browser's console.

You also can't view the contents of the session, because they are never passed to the browser.

When PHP creates a session, it (often times) sets a cookie called PHPSESSID.  The value of this cookie is the only thing sent to the browser.  This value references something on the server (usually a file containing a serialized version of all of the session data).  Unless the author of the site explicitly writes the session data out to the browser, the browser will never have access to it.

Comment: Thank you Nick! What I am still wondering about is; is it possible the website owner gets sensitive information e.g. browsing history, other cookies,.. from the user/web visitor and stores it in that PHPSESSID? (Without notice of the user because he can't view the contents of the session?)

Comment: Not from other sites. A website that you visit only has information from you that you send to it. The only information that the browser will send will be what you send (i.e. filling out a form), or what the server originally sent to the browser to begin with (i.e. a cookie). A website cannot access cookies in your browser from another website.